# Seaborn scatterplot overlaping points in y-tick

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have this scatterplot:

[image]

I wanna make it look like the example below , but I couldn't find nothing in the documentation:

[image]

My pandas Dataframe is here:

```
Year,UserStudy_NumParticipants
2019,40
2019,30
2018,10
2018,2
2018,623
2018,10
2018,43
2018,44
2018,36
2018,60
2018,22
2018,129
2017,20
2017,16
2017,18
2017,20
2017,30
2017,31
2016,40
2016,250
2016,28
2016,40
2016,39
2016,171
2015,40
2015,2
2015,150
2015,30
2015,45
2015,225
2015,50
2015,5
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this [swarm plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html#seaborn.swarmplot) if you can use seaborn.

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'Year':[2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015], 'UserStudy_NumParticipants': [40 ,30 ,10 ,2 ,623 ,10 ,43 ,44 ,36 ,60 ,22 ,129 ,20 ,16 ,18 ,20 ,30 ,31 ,40 ,250 ,28 ,40 ,39 ,171 ,40 ,2 ,150 ,30 ,45 ,225 ,50 ,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="UserStudy_NumParticipants", y="Year", data=df,size=10, orient='h')
```

[image: Swarm Plot]